# Слияние манифеста библиотеки (два контент провайдера)

Tags: android

Делаю библиотеку, внутри которого нужно иметь провайдер. Но если в манифесте проекта к которому подключается библиотека уже есть свой провайдер, то происходит ошибка при компиляции.

Как можно объединить оба провайдера в итоговый манифест? Но так чтобы authorities не менялись (все оставалось как есть)

Манифест основного приложения (это как пример, да деле может быть что угодно)

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
    //...
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.appFileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Манифест библиотеки

```
 <application>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.libFileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/libpaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Итоговый манифест должен быть таким:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
    //...
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.appFileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.libFileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/libpaths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Такая ошибка при компиляции:

> /Users/nameny/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-67
> Error:    Attribute
> provider#androidx.core.content.FileProvider@authorities
> value=(ru.mydomain.myapplication.appFileProvider) from
> AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-67  is also present at [:mylibrary]
> AndroidManifest.xml:12:13-67
> value=(ru.mydomain.myapplication.libFileProvider).    Suggestion: add
> 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to  element at
> AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-29:20 to override.
> /Users/nameny/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:28:17-50
> Error:    Attribute
> meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@resource
> value=(@xml/filepaths) from AndroidManifest.xml:28:17-50  is also
> present at [:mylibrary] AndroidManifest.xml:17:17-49
> value=(@xml/libpaths).    Suggestion: add
> 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to  element at
> AndroidManifest.xml:26:13-28:53 to override.

Comment: А каким вы представляете себе итоговый манифест? Сообщение об ошибке вам подсказывает решение, помогите утилите понять что вы хотите получить. https://android-doc.github.io/tools/building/manifest-merge.html

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja добавил как я представляю итоговый манифест. Но не смог понять, как решить проблему с помощью тегов решения конфликта, поэтому и задал вопрос.

Comment: Не нашёл подтверждения, но судя по всему идентификатором тэга является атрибут `name`. В обоих случаях он одинаковый (`androidx.core.content.FileProvider`) и происходит попытка слияния содержимого в один провайдер. На ум приходит наследовать этого провайдера и уже наследника прописывать в манифест, но не очень понимаю как это будет работать.

Comment: @woesss спасибо! так и есть, все работает!